# ASP.NET FormsAuthenticationModule DefaultUrl overriding explicit

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a mature ASP.NET web application using FormsAuthentication (FA) to manage logins.  Under certain situations, I would like to redirect the "just logged in" user to a different URL to the one that FA uses.  As per standard functionality, FA will redirect to our normal homepage (specified in web.config) unless a redirectUrl was used when it hits a page that requires an authenticated user.

In my system, after the user's username/password is validated I typically use

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, createPersistentCookie: true); // Also calls SetAuthCookie()
```

which handles most situations.  However, depending on certain conditions (primarily based on the newly logged in user's role) I want to redirect to a different destination.  My thoughts for doing this are to call `SetAuthCookie()` myself and then use `Response.Redirect(myUrl, false);` and `ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`.

Despite doing this, the very next request comes in using for the URL defined in my  tag of web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="120" cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="~/?raspberry=true" />
</authentication>
```

Here is the actual code I am using (if a different url is required, it is specified by the `overrideUrl` parameter:

```
    internal static void CreateTicket(string userName, string overrideUrl)
    {
        // Ref: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

        if (overrideUrl == null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, createPersistentCookie: true); // Includes call to SetAuthCookie()
        }
        else
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie: true, strCookiePath:FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(overrideUrl, false);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
```

If I pass in a value of `/special/path` for `overrideUrl` I would like the next request to come in to be '/special/path'.  Instead I am seeing `/?raspberry=true`

Is something else forcing defaultUrl?
Is there a way to "snoop" into the Response object while debugging to see if a Redirect is already in place? or set a breakpoint whenever it gets set so I can look at the call stack?

EDIT: At the end of my method, the Response object is showing the following properties:

```
RedirectLocation: "/special/path"
Status: "302 Found"
StatusCode: 302
StatusDescription: "Found"
IsRequestBeingRedirected: true
HeadersWritten: false
```

which all looks absolutely correct.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: I've had a look through the Reference Source of the [FormsAuthentication](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/FormsAuthenticationModule.cs,0b747e35c2caa2bd) Module's `OnLeave()` method and seen that it checks a property called `Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect`).  I though setting this to `true` would fix the problem (because I can only assume it is the FA module at the end of the pipeline overriding the value).  But no!  Setting this to true doesn't fix the problem!!!

Comment: My above code is called from the `Authenticate` event of a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login` inside a UserControl on my login page.

After steping right back out to that method, the Response properties are still correct, however the next "Debugger Step" takes me to the Render method of another User control and I can see that `Response.RedirectLocation` has at that point been reverted to `"/?raspberry=true"` so something "magical" in the ASP.NET framework between those two event shandlers is kiboshing my carefully set Redirect :-(  I'm now can't believe it is the FormsAuthentication module. :

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I can see what is causing it.  It is the fact that I am using the `Login` Web Control and running my code as part of the `Authenticate` event.  Looking at the reference source for the [Login Web Control](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Web/UI/WebControls/login.cs.html#https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Web/UI/WebControls/login.cs.html,2a9f2be3c6dfcc35,references), the `Authenticate` event is raised by its `AttemptLogin` method (search for it in ref source).  After raising the event and seeing that Authentication was successful, it then goes on to:

1. Call SetAuthCookie itself (I've already done this myself but presumably the only thing I should be doing in my code is determining if authentication was successful or not, and not messing with AuthCookie or redirects)
2. Performing a Redirect (overwriting my carefully crafted Redirect)

I'm going to have to figure out a solution as there these methods are private (can't override by inheriting the usercontrol) and there appears to be no option for overring or suppressing the user of it's GetRedirectUrl().